# stored procedure returning only reference fields

Tags: linq-to-sql

have a stored procedure with 1 input and 2 reference parameters. When assigning the stored procedure to a linq-query the query is not executed. What should I do to really execute the query which fills the 2 reference parameters. All examples I found at the internet use 'foreach' statements but the sp isn't returning a list of results.

the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStraatenPlaatsnaam]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
-- <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
-- <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
@POSTCODE nvarchar(6) 
,@STRAAT nvarchar(17) out
,@PLAATS nvarchar(18) out

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    @STRAAT = PCT_STRAATNAAM_TNT
   ,@PLAATS  = PCT_WOONPLAATS_TNT
FROM
    PCTR
WHERE 
    PCT_POSTCODE = @POSTCODE 
END
```

The Procedure is a given fact with no allowance to change. How can I call and execute this procedure using LinqToSQL? The Procedure is already used for a number of other processes and has worked for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using output parameter as 'out' keyword which merely used in PL-Sql(Oracle)....Instead, you have to use 'OUTPUT' keyword for output parameter in T-Sql(Sql Server)....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetStraatenPlaatsnaam]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
-- <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
-- <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
@POSTCODE nvarchar(6) 
,@STRAAT nvarchar(17) OUTPUT
,@PLAATS nvarchar(18) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
   @STRAAT = PCT_STRAATNAAM_TNT
   ,@PLAATS  = PCT_WOONPLAATS_TNT
FROM
PCTR
   WHERE 
   PCT_POSTCODE = @POSTCODE 

END
```